# Select query in mysql/php does not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote a simple code for login page using PHP and Mysql
but it always return the false value in the condition (if).
whats wrong?
this is my code :

```
..... (successfully connected to database)
$User = $_POST['username'];
    $Pass = md5($_POST['password']);

      $sql = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Username=$User and Password=$Pass";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
      if($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $User;
            header( 'Location: panel.php' ) ;
        }

         else {
               header( 'Location: login.php?status=1' ) ;
              }
    }
```

Comment: You're not treating your variables in your `WHERE` clause as strings; quote them. Plus, you are wide open to injection and for many reasons.

Comment: thank you fred... but i didn't understand it :D may you explain?

Comment: You're welcome do this => `WHERE Username='$User' and Password='$Pass'`

Comment: Many things can be wrong. Was the password originally created using MD5. Is the column VARCHAR and long enough to accomodate its length. Do your form elements contain name attributes. All these can and will contribute to a query failing. Also, you're using sessions. Did you start the session? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, including checking for errors in your query.

Comment: Plus whatever is inside `panel.php` will also be a factor. Replace `header( 'Location: panel.php' ) ;` with `echo "Success";` if it shows that, then you will know the problem is in `panel.php`

Comment: If you don't or can't answer any of my comments, then I won't be able to further help you. Good luck.

Comment: yeah sir, please wait, im chekin

Comment: it's not the problem of panel.php.... it always does else!

Comment: `$conn` for me, says that your DB connection is `mysqli_` using an Object oriented style, and not `mysql_`. Do you know the difference between both of these? Show me the rest of your code where you connect, replacing credentials with `xxx`.

Comment: i fixed it as you said! tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am under the impression that you are using an Object oriented style to connect with when using `mysqli_` functions as per `$result = $conn->query($sql);` then using a `mysql_` function `mysql_num_rows()` after.

- `mysql_` does not support this method.

Example of an object oriented style of connection as per the manual
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

*Sidenote:* If this isn't the case, then you will need to show us what API you are using to connect to your database with.

Plus, the fact that it's already been established in comments that you need to quote your variables in the `WHERE` clause.

Therefore you need to change

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

to

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

or

```
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

as per http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php using an Object oriented style.

and the `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE Username='$User' and Password='$Pass'
```

---

I noticed you are using MD5. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged, since it is old and considered "broken".

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection which is something your code is subject to,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

@Fred -ii- is right.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Username=$User and Password=$Pass";
```

will result in this query being sent to the database:

```
SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Username=user and Password=password
```

You need to quote the `user` and `password`, otherwise MySQL will not know they're strings:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Username='$User' and Password='$Pass'";
```

Comment: Are the values of `$User` and `$Password` correct? What about `$count` ?

Comment: $User and $Password are working correctly... but i dont know about count!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get $count would be

```
$count = $result->rowCount();
```

I'll add more to this answer if there are further problems.